# EventBus with Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

How would you write something like a simple EventBus sample like the following with Rx?

```
public class EventBus
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, List<Action<Event>>> routes = new Dictionary<Type, List<Action<Event>>>();

    public void RegisterHandler<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : Event
    {
        List<Action<Event>> handlers;

        if (!this.routes.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out handlers))
        {
            handlers = new List<Action<Event>>();
            this.routes.Add(typeof(T), handlers);
        }

        handlers.Add(x => handler((T)x));
    }

    public void Publish<T>(T @event) where T : Event
    {
        List<Action<Event>> handlers;

        if (!this.routes.TryGetValue(@event.GetType(), out handlers))
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            var apply = handler;
            apply(@event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is something similar here https://github.com/shiftkey/Reactive.EventAggregator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the functionality of your `EventBus` is rather basic, I think that something like that might be good enough for you:

```
public class EventBus
{
    private readonly Subject<Event> subject = new Subject<Event>();

    public IObservable<T> GetEventStream<T>() where T : Event
    {
        return subject.OfType<T>();
    }

    public void Publish<T>(T @event) where T : Event
    {
        subject.OnNext(@event);
    }
}
```

In that solution, instead of registering `Action<T>`, you simply subscribe to the stream of events:

```
var bus = new EventBus();
var disposable = bus.GetEventStream<SomeEvent>.Subscribe(ev => Console.WriteLine("It happened!"));
// some time later
bus.Publish(new SomeEvent());
// you can also unsubscribe from the stream
disposable.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Reflection;

  public abstract class RegistrationBusBase
  {
    protected readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Guid, Action<IMessage>>> routes = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Guid, Action<IMessage>>>();

    private static MethodInfo createActionMethod;
    private static MethodInfo registerMethod;

    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribes all IEventHandler derivations located in the given assembly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="assembly">The assembly to search for IEventHandler derivations.</param>
    /// <param name="eventsHandlerFactory">A factory capable of producing a concrete implementation of each IEventHandler.</param>
    public static void Subscribe(IBus bus, Assembly assembly, Func<Type, IEventsHandler> eventsHandlerFactory)
    {
      IEnumerable<Type> handlers = assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Any(y => y.IsGenericType && y.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEventHandler<>)));
      foreach (Type handlerType in handlers)
      {
        IEventsHandler eventsHandler = eventsHandlerFactory(handlerType);
        if (eventsHandler == null)
        {
          throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("No handler for {0} found in the eventsHandlerFactory", handlerType.FullName));
        }
        else
        {
          bus.Subscribe(eventsHandler);
        }
      }
    }

    public void RegisterCommandHandler<T>(Action<T> handler, SubscriptionDisposer subscriptionDisposer) where T : ICommand
    {
      this.RegisterHandler<T>(handler, subscriptionDisposer);
    }

    public void RegisterEventHandler<T>(Action<T> handler, SubscriptionDisposer subscriptionDisposer) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
      this.RegisterHandler<T>(handler, subscriptionDisposer);
    }

    public Action<TEvent> CreatePublishAction<TEvent, TEventHandler>(TEventHandler eventHandler)
      where TEvent : IDomainEvent
      where TEventHandler : IEventHandler<TEvent>
    {
      return eventHandler.Handle;
    }

    public Action<TCommand> CreateSendAction<TCommand, TCommandHandler>(TCommandHandler commandHandler)
      where TCommand : ICommand
      where TCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    {
      return commandHandler.Handle;
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe<M>(Action<M> subscription)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public abstract IDisposable Subscribe(object subscriber);

    internal void DeregisterHandler(Type type, Guid handler)
    {
      Dictionary<Guid, Action<IMessage>> handlers;
      if (this.routes.TryGetValue(type, out handlers))
      {
        handlers.Remove(handler);
      }
    }

    protected IDisposable RegisterAllHandlersByReflection(object eventHandler)
    {
      SubscriptionDisposer subscriptionDisposer = new SubscriptionDisposer(this);
      this.RegisterAllEventHandlersByReflection(eventHandler, subscriptionDisposer);
      this.RegisterAllCommandHandlersByReflection(eventHandler, subscriptionDisposer);
      return subscriptionDisposer;
    }

    private void RegisterHandler<T>(Action<T> handler, SubscriptionDisposer subscriptionDisposer) where T : IMessage
    {
      Dictionary<Guid, Action<IMessage>> handlers;
      if (!this.routes.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out handlers))
      {
        handlers = new Dictionary<Guid, Action<IMessage>>();
        this.routes.Add(typeof(T), handlers);
      }

      Guid handlerID = Guid.NewGuid();
      Action<IMessage> adjustedHandler = DelegateAdjuster.CastArgument<IMessage, T>(x => handler(x));
      handlers.Add(handlerID, adjustedHandler);
      subscriptionDisposer.AddHandler(typeof(T), handlerID);
    }

    private void RegisterAllEventHandlersByReflection(object eventHandler, SubscriptionDisposer subscriptionDisposer)
    {
      IEnumerable<Type> handleEventTypes = eventHandler.GetType().GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEventHandler<>));
      foreach (Type handleEventType in handleEventTypes)
      {
        this.RegisterEventHandler(handleEventType, eventHandler, subscriptionDisposer);
      }
    }

    private void RegisterAllCommandHandlersByReflection(object handler, SubscriptionDisposer subscriptionDisposer)
    {
      IEnumerable<Type> handlerTypes = handler.GetType().GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
      foreach (Type handlerType in handlerTypes)
      {
        this.RegisterCommandHandler(handlerType, handler, subscriptionDisposer);
      }
    }

    private void RegisterEventHandler(Type handleEventType, object eventHandler, SubscriptionDisposer subscriptionDisposer)
    {
      createActionMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("CreatePublishAction");
      registerMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("RegisterEventHandler");
      var genericArgs = handleEventType.GetGenericArguments();
      foreach (var genericArg in genericArgs)
      {
        var action = this.CreateTheProperAction(genericArg, eventHandler);
        this.RegisterTheCreatedAction(genericArg, action, subscriptionDisposer);
      }
    }

    private void RegisterCommandHandler(Type handleEventType, object eventHandler, SubscriptionDisposer subscriptionDisposer)
    {
      createActionMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("CreateSendAction");
      registerMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("RegisterCommandHandler");
      var genericArgs = handleEventType.GetGenericArguments();
      foreach (var genericArg in genericArgs)
      {
        var action = this.CreateTheProperAction(genericArg, eventHandler);
        this.RegisterTheCreatedAction(genericArg, action, subscriptionDisposer);
      }
    }

    private void RegisterTheCreatedAction(Type handlerType, object action, SubscriptionDisposer subscriptionDisposer)
    {
      registerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(handlerType).Invoke(this, new[]
      {
        action,
        subscriptionDisposer
      });
    }

    private object CreateTheProperAction(Type handlerType, object handler)
    {
      return createActionMethod.MakeGenericMethod(handlerType, handler.GetType()).Invoke(this, new[] { handler });
    }
  }
```

Comment: hmm, looks way too complicated for such a simple task.